# CustomControl Binding error before OnApplyTemplate has the chance to set DataContext on root element

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, custom-controls, datacontext

I've got a Custom Control. The `ControlTemplate` is in the Generic.xaml file.
The class of the control contains an override of the `OnApplyTemplate` method.

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        var textBox = Template.FindName("PART_textBox", this) as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            textBox.GotFocus += PART_textBox_GotFocus;
            textBox.LostFocus += PART_textBox_LostFocus;
        }

        var grid = Template.FindName("PART_grid", this) as Grid;
        if (grid != null)
        {
            grid.DataContext = this;
        }
    }
```

The root element in my control template is a `Grid`. I want to set the data context of the root element.
I override `OnApplyTemplate` to be able to attach events to controls in the template, and to set the data context of the grid.

The problem appears when my custom control is used in a view. During the initialisation of the control, binding errors are shown in the console. All bindings from the controls in the template of the custom control and the data context fail the first time, because the data context is not yet set. As soon as `OnApplyTemplate` is called in the custom control (still speaking about the 'initialization'), the datacontext is set, and everything works correctly. It's not a visible problem, the user won't notice this at all. But the errors are shown in the console, which means I do something wrong.
Setting the DataContext in the constructor of the custom control won't help because the (built-in) `Template` property is not set at that stage.

<sub>I'm setting the datacontext of the Grid to the class of the custom control itself, which is not recommended, but it won't change the cause of the problem.</sub>

Comment: did u tried applying the base.OnApplyTemplate after the code changes?

Answer (score 0):

You could bind to a property of the control itself in XAML using either `{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}` or `{RelativeSource AncestorType=local:YourControl}`.

You shouldn't set the `DataContext` of the control in `OnApplyTemplate()`. This will prevent your control from inherit a `DataContext` from a parent in the element tree, as you would expect as a consumer of the control.